# Python Multiprocessing For Loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a for loop that loops over 5000 days worth of data points. For each day there are 500 class instances that needs to process each of those events. For example:

```
class SimpleClass:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.final_value = 0
    def process(self,x):
        self.final_value = x+1   #this is an absurd simplification

# Create N Class instances
ind = []
for i in xrange(0,500):
    ind.append( SimpleClass(str(i)) )

# Main processing loop
for j in xrange(0,5000):

    # Is there a way of speeding this up?
    for k in ind:
        k.process(j)
```

This above is a really simple example but its highlights what I am trying to do. The inner for loop is obviously slow, but if I can parallelize it, or any way of sleep the consumption of those `j` then it will speed it up. Any ideas?  I have not much experience in multiprocessing library.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) Python library, particularly the `map()` and its "iterable" (rather than list builder) counterpart `imap()`. The documentation includes examples that seem to me quite close to what you are trying to do.

But you must know that if the performances of your program are limited by the CPU speed, this will probably not help you because of the GIL ([Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)).